# Java Replace whitespace

Tags: java, whitespace

No matter what I seem to try, replacing the white space with an input of

```
2x= -3
```

will result in the string being truncated to just 2x=.

```
public void parseEquation(String x){
    String adf = x;
    String z = adf.replaceAll("\\s","");
    System.out.println(z);
}
```

The first line is my input, the next line is my output

[image: fail]

Comment: Use `StringBuilder` for such string operations

Comment: String adf = x;
is redundant here as replaceAll creates a new String

Answer (score 7):

Turns out i have severe mental problems.

I was using the

> new Scanner.next();

vs

> new Scanner.nextLine();

Comment: **severe** mental problems

Answer (score 1):

If using other libraries is an option, consider [StringUtils.deleteWhitespace](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#deleteWhitespace%28java.lang.String%29) . Its a well known library, well tested, and used in lots of projects so it is likely better and faster than what you could do on your own.

It also takes care of tabs and other non-printables. I'm not sure if the regex `\s` does that or not.